# Find "Guest" from df1 in df2 and create 3rd DataFrame with the combined info

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames `df1` and `df2`. The two `df`'s are of different length. `df1` is appointments and `df2` is sales. I will eventually want to find sales % of consults (`df1['Service']`) that turned into a sale (this is end game not needed at the moment).

For now I want to find if "Guest" in `df1` is also in `df2` (meaning a service/consult turned into a sale) and if so I want a 3rd DataFrame created with the combined data of `'Guest'` from `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1[['Guest', 'Therapist', 'Service', 'StartTime', 'Status']]

df2[['Guest', 'ProductName', 'Quantity']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `where` and `isin`:

```
df3 = df1["Guest"].where(df1["Guest"].isin(df2["Guest"].tolist())).dropna()
```

To get a DataFrame with all columns, you could use `merge` instead:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="Guest")
```

Comment: That works great for pulling just the "Guest" name from the 2 df's and creating a 3rd df, but Is there a way to pull all the other columns along with it? df3 would have [['Guest' , 'Therapist' , 'Service', 'StartTime', 'Status', 'ProductName' , 'Quantity'] ? Thank you.